# Loop through Folder & SubFolders, inserting Path & Filename as Text into header, Print, Close without saving

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to loop through a lot of Templates that are data enabled and insert the Path & Filename as Text into the header, so that when I print them showing codes not values, it doesn't affect the Path/Filenames. So my task is to do this in this order:

1. Open Template (unless it can be done programatically!)
2. Insert Path & Filename as Text into header
3. Send to Print
4. Quit without saving Template
5. Do next Template

Here's what I have to loop through the folders...

```
Sub PrintAllFilesInAFolder()
 Dim sMyDir As String
 Dim sDocName As String

 ' The path to obtain the files.
 sMyDir = "C:\SomeFolder\SomeSubFolder\SomeDocument\"

 sDocName = Dir(sMyDir & "*.dotx")

 While sDocName <> ""
 ' Print the file.
 Application.PrintOut FileName:=sMyDir & sDocName
 ' Get next file name.
 sDocName = Dir()
 Wend

End Sub
```

Don't know how to do it, so I'd be extremely grateful if someone could slot the vba in where I need it :-)

They are Word 2007 Templates

Comment: As it stands, your question is "too broad". As explained in the site [help] questions on Stack Overflow should be narrowly targeted: one question at a time. It's good that you've posted the code you already have and I'm going to help you get started. But keep the point in mind for the future, please. I'm editing your post to narrow the scope (remove some of the questions). Please ask a *new* question then to follow-up (go to the next step).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PrintAllFilesInAFolder()
   Dim sMyDir As String
   Dim sDocName As String
   Dim doc As Document

   ' The path to obtain the files.
   sMyDir = "H:\WORK RELATED\TESTING MACROS\"

   sDocName = Dir(sMyDir & "*.doc")

   While sDocName <> ""
     ' Open the file.
     Set doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sMyDir & sDocName)
        Call PathFileNameInHeader ' Gets macro to insert field in header
     Application.PrintOut FileName:=sMyDir & sDocName 'Prints document in current 
folder
     doc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
     ' Get next file name.
     sDocName = Dir()
   Wend
End Sub


Sub PathFileNameInHeader()
'
' Inserts Path & Filename field in header, then converts field to plain text
'
'
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
        Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "FILENAME  \* Caps \p ", PreserveFormatting:=True
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
            Selection.Fields.Unlink
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

End Sub
```

I've tested this numerous times and it works for me.